# Identity of the Operator Norm applied to the differential $df$ for convex $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f \in C^1(U, \mathbb{R}^k)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

In my Analysis II Script they often use 'special' norms such as the Operator norm to make proofs more 'elegant' or just shorter. There is also the following statement *(without a proof)* which I can't figure out on my own:

> **Lemma** Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be convex and $f \in C^1(U, \mathbb{R}^k)$ then we have $$ [f]_U: = \sup_{\substack{u,v \in U\\u\neq v}} \frac{|f(u)-f(v)|}{|u-v|}= \sup_{z \in U} \|df|_z\|_O \tag{*}$$

**My problems**: Although I believe to understand the definitions I fell terribly lost on how to show such a statement. Rigorously I want to show the both inequalities but I fail to see any relation:

1) I don't see why the function has to be $C^1$, of course it has to be differentiable otherwise the notion of the linear function $df|_z: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ would make no sense, but I don't see why all partial derivatives have to be continuous on top of that.

I assume that one is supposed to show the "$\geq$" by making fact of the $C^1$ and interpret the differential $df$ through it's Jacobi-Matrix representation. In that case however I find it utterly hard to establish a connection between the partial derivatives and $f$

2) I don't see  in which step I have to make use of the fact that $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex, that means $\forall x,y : [x,y] \subset U$ where $[x,y]$ corresponds to the line $(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y \in U$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$

---

**My approach**: I couldn't do much besides start with the idea that $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is differentiable, which means that: $$\forall z \in U, \exists df|_z  \in \hom(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^k) : f(z+h)-f(z)-df|_z(h)=o(h) $$
I wanted to make the left side of (*) look more like the statement above so I did substitute $h:= u-v$ and I believe thanks to $U$ being convex if $h \in U$ it would follow that $u,v \in U$ but I am not sure here. Mainly I would end up with the statement $$ \sup_{{\substack{h \in U\\h\neq 0}}} \frac{|f(h+v)-f(v)|}{|h|}$$
But I see no chance in getting the relation between this and the differential $df|_z$

**Updated**: For $\leq$ I thought I might could try the following argumentation: $$|f(z+h)-f(z)|=|df|_z(h)+o(h)| \leq \| df|_z \|_O |h| + |o(h)| $$ having $h \in U\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ I could divide the above expression by $|h|$ and take the supremum, that doesn't readily imply the desired $\leq$ but it is somewhat close.

Comment: Upvoted only to cancel the meaningless downvote.

Comment: Since this is functional-analysis problem introduced in a analysis II script (multivariate calculus) I'd also gladly read on some literature advice dealing with such operator norm identities. The identity was given no name whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference : 355p in the book ${\it mathematical\ analysis}$- Apostol

Since $U$ is convex then there exists a line between $u$ and $v$ when $u,\ v\in U$.

Fix $u,\ v$:

**MVT** : Let ${\bf f} : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. For every ${\bf a}\in \mathbb{R}^m$, there exists ${\bf z}\in \overline{{\bf uv}} $ : 
  $$ \langle {\bf a},  {\bf f}({\bf u})-{\bf f}({\bf v})\rangle =\langle {\bf a},d{\bf f}'({\bf z})({\bf u}-{\bf v})\rangle $$

Then if $a=f(u)-f(v)$ then $$|f(u)-f(v)|^2 \leq |f(u)-f(v)| |df'(z)(u-v)|$$

Comment: This seems to be way above my level, mind to elaborate on your steps? Where do your variables come from? $u,v \in U$ I suppose, what is $\overline{u} \in U$ the conjugate of said number? -- I get it, you refer to the mean value theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ !!

Comment: Yes I mean MVT in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I believe the MVT Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ only applies for real valued function, that is for functions $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ but in this exercise my function is vector valued, I suppose I need a generalization of it, or a boundary condition.

Comment: Yes. carefully read answer please. in theorem $f$ is vector valued. I will edit.

Comment: I appreciate your patience, thanks for your continuous elaboration and effort.